Does the PayPal Checkout Standard integration support Apple Pay and Google Pay out of the box?
I'm looking to implement a hosted checkout experience that supports Apple and Google Pay out of the box, without having to do a lot of complex integration work. To accomplish this, I'm trying to integrate PayPal Checkout (Standard) on our website, but it's unclear whether Apple Pay and Google Pay are supported out of the box (this blog post implies yes: https://developer.paypal.com/community/blog/apple-pay-integration-options-with-paypal/#production-errors), or whether I have to integrate with both the PayPal API as well as the Google Pay and Apple Pay APIs directly. Is a fully hosted PayPal Checkout supporting Apple and Google Pay possible? Note that we were not approved for Braintree, so we can't use that.

No, for PayPal Apple Pay and Google Pay are part of an advanced integration, not a standard one, and require additional setup per PayPal's guides for each payment method.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/apm/apple-pay/
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/apm/google-pay/

